# How to copy PDS member(s) from another volume in USS

Tags: mainframe

I am trying to copy some members of the SYS1.PROCLIB in another volume to compare against what is currently being IPL.
On the Unix System Services command line;

```
>tsocmd "allocate file(srcds) dsn('SYS1.PROCLIB(MEMBER1)' unit(3390) volume(AWAY_VOL) SHR"
>tsocmd "allocate file(dstds) dsn('USER.SYS1.PROCLIB') unit(3390) dsorg(PO) recfm(F,B) lrecl(80) block(800) NEW CATALOG"
>tso "ocopy INDD(srcds) OUTDD(dstds) TEXT"
ocopy INDD(srcds) OUTDD(dstds) TEXT
IKJ56247I FILE INFO-RETRIEVAL NOT PERFORMED, IS NOT ALLOCATED
RC(12)
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong such that either the source dataset or the destination dataset cannot be retrieve.  How do I accomplish what I want without having to use JCL or REXX?

Comment: MY first guess would be that you try to create USER.SYS1.PROCLIB although it already exists.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure that is eliminated as the source of the error as I have already ran a tsocmd "delete USER.SYS1.PROCLIB'" first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the OMVS environment why not just copy the members of each PDS to a directory and then you can use the diff, or whatever tool you wish, to compare.

Another option, if you are z/OS 2.5 (or 3.1), is to enable DSFS and then you can use the native OMVS command to compare the members of each PDS without having to copy as DSFS allows direct access to z/OS datasets from the OMVS environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don’t understand why you want to allocate `SYS1.PROCLIB` in the first command. You might not even be authorized to create a `SYS1.*` dataset.
2. Allocating the target file is correct. Then you would have just to copy.

If still failing, it could be that there’s not enough space in the target volume.